# Insert XML to XML Document at specified tag

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I am working on XML where I want to insert below XML tag into parent xml:

> ```
> <Subject></Subject>
> ```

Parent XML

> ```
> <School>
>    <ClassB></ClassB>
>    <ClassA>
>       <Students>
>       </Students>
>    </ClassA>
> </School>
> ```

want the final out put as

> ```
> <School>
>    <ClassB></ClassB>
>    <ClassA>
>       <Subject></Subject>
>       <Students>
>       </Students>
>    </ClassA>
> </School>
> ```

Tried by below code:

> ```
> XmlDocument xmlRequest = new XmlDocument();
>  xmlRequest.LoadXml(parentXML);
>  XmlDocumentFragment xmlfrag = xmlRequest.CreateDocumentFragment();
>  xmlfrag.InnerXml = xmlSubjects;
>  xmlRequest.DocumentElement.InsertBefore(xmlfrag,  xmlRequest.DocumentElement.FirstChild);
> ```

This will insert Subject element right after School. So How to insert at specific path. In this case under ClassA element.

Please help me here.

Comment: So you want to find (e.g. SelectSingleNode("School/ClassA/Students") and then call it's InsertBefore Method ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use GetElementByName or some method to get the ClassA node:

```
XmlNode xNode = xmlRequest.SelectSingleNode("School/ClassA");
```

Then add Subject as a new child node:

```
XmlNode newNode = xmlRequest.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Subject", Nothing);
xNode.AppendChild(newNode);
```

If you want to add it in a specific place, enumerate the parent node and the existing node, and then use InsertBefore:

```
XmlNode xNode = xmlRequest.SelectSingleNode("School/ClassA");
XmlNode siblingNode = xmlRequest.SelectSingleNode("School/ClassA/Students");
XmlNode newNode = xmlRequest.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Subject", Nothing);
xNode.InsertBefore(xNode, xSibling);
```

Comment: But it will insert Subject tag after Students tag. I want it to be inserted as a first child of ClassA

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether it's the first child or the second child unless you are blindly using indexes to find children instead of names.  Anyway, after you add it, you can change the position of the Students and Subject elements using InsertBefore, where `xNode` is the new node that you created, this will move it above the previous sibling:  `XmlNode xNode = XmlNode = xmlConfig.SelectSingleNode(XPath);
        XmlNode xSibling = xNode.PreviousSibling;
        XmlNode xParent = xNode.ParentNode;

        xParent.InsertBefore(xNode, xSibling);`

Comment: Also, if you want very specific results, be sure to get all of your criteria in the question.  The question only asked that it be under the ClassA node, not that it needed to be the first child in the ClassA node.

Comment: Thank you. Next time i will make sure with question. It worked well for me